# Android Intent Filters for VIEW/EDIT/INSERT Contact

Tags: android, filter, view, android-intent, contacts

I've been trying to find one or all of the right filters.  Does anyone have them?  Down at the bottom you can see the logging output of the intents.  Perhaps they aren't public?

Have tried the following in my code to no avail...

```
  <receiver android:name=".ContactsBroadcastReceiver" android:label="@string/broadcast_receiver_name" android:enabled="true">
       <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/person" android:host="contacts" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" android:host="com.android.contacts" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.LIST_DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.LIST_CONTACTS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.LIST_ALL_CONTACTS" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.LIST_CONTACTS_WITH_PHONES" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/starredList">
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.LIST_STARRED" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/frequentList">
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.LIST_FREQUENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:label="@string/strequentList">
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.LIST_STREQUENT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.TAB" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT_OR_EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.android.contacts" android:pathPrefix="raw_contacts" 
             android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.SHOW_OR_CREATE_CONTACT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.android.contacts" android:path="contacts" 
             android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.android.contacts" android:pathPrefix="contacts" 
             android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact"/>
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="com.android.contacts.action.INSERT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:scheme="content" android:host="com.android.contacts" android:path="contacts" 
             android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact"/>
            <!--
            I/ActivityManager( 1212): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.VIEW dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts flg=0x10000000 cmp=com.android.contacts/.DialtactsContactsEntryActivity bnds=[324,598][480,718] }
            I/ActivityManager( 1212): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.EDIT dat=content://com.android.contacts/raw_contacts/26 cmp=android/com.android.internal.app.ResolverActivity }
            I/ActivityManager( 1212): Starting activity: Intent { act=android.intent.action.INSERT dat=content://com.android.contacts/contacts cmp=com.android.contacts/.ui.EditContactActivity }
             -->
        </intent-filter>
  </receiver>
```

Answer (score 0):

This worked for me:

```
        <intent-filter android:label="Edit Contact">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.EDIT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person"
                android:host="contacts" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact"
                android:host="com.android.contacts" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact"
                android:host="com.android.contacts" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="Create Contact">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.INSERT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/person" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/contact" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.dir/raw_contact" />
        </intent-filter>
        <intent-filter android:label="View Contact">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/person"
                android:host="contacts" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/contact"
                android:host="com.android.contacts" />
            <data android:mimeType="vnd.android.cursor.item/raw_contact"
                android:host="com.android.contacts" />
        </intent-filter>
```

Comment: how to use can u plz give description for this code.
if possible give a simple example.

Comment: What these did to me was to allow my app to receive intents before adding a user. It makes the OS ask the user which app you want to use when adding a new user. Does not do what is being asked in the original question