# How to give an option to start my own application from the native android contact details page?

Tags: android, android-layout

I am taking the reference of one application from android market and I want a similar interface actually so the actual problem goes like this:

Step 1) We have our native contact list in android Phone right please see the screen shot attached:

[image: NativePhoneBook]

Step2) Now i select a Particular Contact from this contact List Lets say I select Narendra Kirusa so we will reach to the following Page

[image: On click of a contact Page]

On this Page the Call mobile option is the default one of the android Phone but after that there is a second row coming with the option of Walkie-talkie thats the customised one by the application developer now when you click on that walkie talkie then it starts your application screenshot attached:

[image: on click of the walkie talkie]

now it lands to  application. Now the thing is where should i make changes do give that option of walkie talkie to start your own  application. like here they gave Walkie talkie on the contact details page the similar option i want to give for my application also then where should i give this option??

1. We cannot make the changes in the OS files as it is the application.
2. There Must be some option in the android-manifest.xml file to give this option of putting a new row to start our own application from the android Native Contact Details Page.I tried googling it but could not figure out much.
3. See there are intents to interact with the native Phone call or SMS so like that only for example to send the sms on click on call phone we can do like this to move it to our application like if you click on call Mobile then we are able to give options like see    on click on the call mobile

If you click on dial it goes to android native phone call and if you click on Send Voice SMS then it goes to my application for this what they did is see in the android-manifest.xml file for mail activity they put this option, i am not sure this can be done 
using Broadcast Receiver or how??

So can you please suggest how I can put a new row after the android native call Mobile row.....??

[image]

Finally how to add this walkie talkie option??

Answer (score 0):

I think here should be used the same mechanism as for opening files in different applications.

You can implement custom BroadcastReceiver which would be registered for receiving this type of action (you'll need to find out what action and category are used)

You can read more about it in docs http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html

Comment: Thanks Marwin for your help..from where i will send the Broadcast for it or the native android is sending this Broadcast?? i am really clueless about it can you please explore it little more?? is there any sample application available for it in android forum or somewhere??

Comment: this intent would be sent by android's contacts application. I think you should google in 'custom broadcast receivers' direction, there must be some examples.

I found this info about intents http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3418586/android-intent-filters-for-view-edit-insert-contact by 'android view contact intent' request in google

Comment: so we ask android to send these intent through as a BroadCast with the help of <intent filter> tag?? and then we will handle that Broadcast in our application and will push our own screen is that a idea but then android native contact detail page will not be opened or are we going to modify the android native Contactdetails Page??

Comment: we are not going to modify anything in android, we just tell android that we can handle this type of intents (intent for calling to contact, by our BroadcastReceiver). After getting intent our app is started where we do what we want. This is how it works, I guess (never tried it myself)

Comment: Marwin thats fine but how the android's native contact details page we addred this option of walkie-talkie row?? if i can add this row then i can control everything i can launch my application or do something else the only problem i have is adding this option walkie talkie to android's native contact details page....??

Comment: as I already said, you only need to implement BroadcastReceiver for this intent and defined in your manifest that you can handle these intents. Contacts app should look for all available calling apps itself

Comment: ohhh you mean this option of row (walkie talkie) will automatically come into the Native Contactdetails Page once i will register this Phone calling intent....??

Comment: yes, it would there as soon as you register your app for receiving this intent type. Same situation can be seen when you choose where to send (different apps) pic from your gallery, for example

Comment: for me this is happening for the calling intent like when i call a contact then a Notification is coming to select option like to make a call or to send a voice sms i did like this see----->          
 <activity
android:name=".NVXSMSLiteActivity"
android:label="@string/app_name" >
<intent-filter>
<action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
<category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />

Comment: </intent-filter>           
<intent-filter android:label="Send Voice SMS">
<action  android:name="android.intent.action.CALL_PRIVILEGED"/> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
<data android:scheme="tel" />
</intent-filter>
<intent-filter android:label="Send Voice SMS">
<action  android:name="android.intent.action.SENDTO"/> 
<category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /> 
<data android:scheme="sms" /> 
<data android:scheme="smsto" /> 
</intentfilter>

Comment: but from the contacts page i am not sure how i will go to details and show this option and which intent i will use anyway let me try out with the custom Broadcast then will let you know.....thanks a lot for all your Help and support Marvin.