# How to introduce myapplciation while saving contacts in android

Tags: android

[How whatsapp is introduced while saving a new contact in this picture?](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LwsRo.png)

I would like to add my own application the same way whats-app has introduced itself in the editing/adding contact (as you can see in the attached image). Unfortunately, I could not find any reference online.

Please help me out here. I am stuck.

Comment: Welcome to SO. I've rephrased your question a bit in an attempt to make it more evident to readers. Please feel free to accept it or tweak it further if I missed the point. Good luck!

Comment: Thanks Ivan. Appreciate it

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create an App, so that when user tries to `Edit Contact`, an Activity from your app should intercept it?

You can create an `Edit Activity` and in the manifest create an IntentFilter for this activity with `action=Intent.ACTION_EDIT`. You will more info here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/5463751/4747587

Comment: Thanks for this quick response Henry. I will post my code as soon as i get it to work or at least to somewhere :)